# Custom Angular Directive not working with dynamic images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on a custom directive for AngularJs that has a image rotator based on a Jquery Plugin I wrote, [which can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/uLEHD/2/)

Here is my directive

```
.directive('imageRotator', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            console.log('Before Function');
            $element.j360();
            console.log('After Function');
        }
    };
});
```

Now the directive works when I hard code the series of images as in the demo, but when I try to make the images dynamic by combining and ng-repeat, the plugin does not work. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654513/angular-directive-within-jquery-plugin-does-not-work) about using `$compile` when using dynamic html which like this:

```
<div class="product" image-Rotator>
    <img ng-repeat="img in page.imgs" class="child" ng-src="img/{{product.sku}}/{{img}}.png">
</div>
```

But when I use `$compile`, I get errors in my console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at link (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/controllers.js:48:14)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:6220:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:5630:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:5633:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:5535:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:5649:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude [as $transclude] (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:6241:18)
    at ngDirective.link (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:19898:16)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:6220:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/angular/angular.js:5630:15) <div class="product" image-rotator="">
```

This maybe a bit over my head as my knowledge of angular isn't great so I'm not sure what the correct way is to make a directive especially with dynamic data.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this to work with dynamic images? Any help or ideas are appreciated.

[Heres a plunker with the directive.](http://plnkr.co/edit/lfWCsVVnhbTV8FZ5RmJ0)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your directive? It would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Working on that right now, one moment

Comment: A plunked has been added

Comment: Is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHWTgImygbXIah3vZz8C) the expected result? If so I can write an answer for it.

Comment: Yes! Please add this to the answers and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your plunker had two problems. I'll start with the simple one

```
<img ng-repeat="img in imgs" class="child" ng-src="'{{src}}'">
```

You are iterating over `imgs` and storing that image object in `img`, because of so your code should look like the following instead.

```
<img ng-repeat="img in imgs" class="child" ng-src="{{img.src}}">
```

Notice the `img.src`. Next was the slightly more confusing issue, you needed to call your jQuery plugin only after AngularJS had created the DOM from the `ng-repeat`. From a couple of google searches and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066239/defer-angularjs-watch-execution-after-digest-raising-dom-event), it seemed that the best way of doing so was to put your plugin call inside of [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout).

```
.directive('imageRotator', function ($timeout) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
          console.log('Before Function');
          $timeout(function() {
            $element.j360();
          });

          console.log('After Function');

      }
  };
});
```

I don't know much about AngularJS, but from what I could gather the `$digest` cycle is responsible for creating the DOM, and using `$timeout` with no delay will wait for the  `$digest` cycle to finish and then execute your function. I may be wrong about this, but it worked for me.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I'll have to read up about using $timeout but everything works great.